# Python - how to replace occurances in text files?

Tags: python, text, file-handling, codio

I am working on my school work for 'Intro to Scripting' and I am stuck on how to replace in a text file.

The challenge is asking me to read the contents of the text file, which I did with the code below:

```
filepath = I

file1 = open(filepath, 'r')
print(file1.read())
file1.close()
```

Now it's asking me to replace the variable set for 'S' with the variable set for 'T', and I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this.

Edit: This is an online class, so peer collaboration is non-existent, we also use Codio for this work, and nothing I've tried from other questions asked has worked, nor does any of the class reading give examples.

Comment: you opening file for reading purpose not writing purpose

Comment: Yes, the challenge is asking me to read the file, then replace the variables.

Comment: you just simple need to Replace 'S' with 'T'

Comment: This is the code we are given to start with

Comment: # Get the filepath from the command line
import sys
I= sys.argv[1] 
O= sys.argv[2] 
S= sys.argv[3]
T= sys.argv[4]

# Your code goes here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am Correct If you want to Just Replace **S** With **T** and save output in another file use following code

```
f1 = open('data.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('output.txt', 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('S', 'T'))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```